# Is Charge Conjugation Representation Dependent?

Tags: conventions, dirac-equation, charge-conjugation

I'm having a problem understanding section 7 of this paper:
http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.1718

The author defines the commonly know $\Psi^c$ as $\textit{C}\Psi \textit{C}^{-1}=\eta \hat{\Psi}$ in equation 7.1 ( here the C's are Operators, not matrices, as he explains in the text). And defines $\hat{\Psi}= \gamma_0 C\Psi^*$ in equation 3.16 .

This translates into $\Psi^c= \gamma_0 C\Psi^*$ which is different from all the other sources I was using!

You can check equation 88 of http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/staff/academic/boyd/stuff/dirac.pdf or the book by David Griffiths or any other mainstream source, an you'll have:

$\Psi^c= C \gamma_0 \Psi^*$

What's going on? Is the definition of $\Psi^c$ representation dependent? Since He gives these definitions when talking about Majorana Fermions and all the other are given when the author is talking about Dirac Fermions...
But how does that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the charge conjugation operator is representation dependent.  The time reversal operator depends on the representation as well, although the parity operator does not.  A key reason for the representation dependence is that the $C$ and $T$ operators involve complex conjugation (although in different ways).  Therefore, their form depends on whether particular $\gamma$-matrices and $\Psi$ itself are complex.  The Majorana representation is specifically designed to give spinors that are their own charge conjugates a particularly simple form; that makes $C$ is this representation different from in the Dirac-Pauli or Weyl representations.

Comment: Yes, of course! The analogy with the T operator made it very clear. Thanks.